# How can I fix 22 invalid argument error(22)?

Tags: c++, sockets

I don't know why keep occurring [22] invalid argument in the process.

the source code like this

```
int MainLoop()
{
        struct  timeval         timeout;
        fd_set  event;
        int             n, maxfd, newfd, rc, err_cnt = 0;
        CSocket* pSocket;
        int             chktime, currtime;
        char    buff[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];

        int                     MaxPosition, CurrPosition = 0;
        WmBoard *pWmBoard;

        MaxPosition  = pCWmBoard->GetMaxPosition();

        g_CAgent.Create(g_CsPort, g_CsAddr);

        chktime = GetTime();

        while(g_Running) {
                timeout.tv_sec =  1;            /* Second */
                timeout.tv_usec = 0;            /* micro Second */

                pSocket = NULL;
                maxfd = g_SockList.GetEventMask(&event);
                n = select(maxfd, &event, (fd_set *)0,(fd_set *)0,
                        (struct timeval *) &timeout);

                if(n > 0) {
                        pSocket = g_SockList.GetEventSock(&event);
                        if(pSocket != NULL)
                        {
                                newfd = pSocket->Accept();
                                if(newfd > 0)
                                {
                                        err_cnt = 0;
                                        pWmBoard = GetMinClientCH(MaxPosition);
                                        if (pWmBoard != NULL)
                                        {
                                                rc = SendFD(pWmBoard->PipeFd, (void *)" ", 1, newfd);
                                                if (rc <= 0)
                                                {
                                                        char  szTmp[128];
                                                        sprintf(szTmp,"FDSend Error=[%d]errno=[%d]",
                                                                                        newfd,errno);
                                                        g_CAgent.SendMessage("!S001", g_PgmName, szTmp);
                                                        g_Log.Write("[%s:%d][E] %s",
                                                                                g_PgmName, g_Pid, szTmp);
                                                        /*
                                                        if(errno == EBADF) g_Running = FALSE;
                                                        */

                                                        #if 0
                                                        if(pWmBoard -> ProcessID > 1)
                                                                kill(pWmBoard->ProcessID, SIGTERM);
                                                        #endif

                                                        pWmBoard->PipeFd = -1;
                                                }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                                g_Log.Write("[%s:%d][E] client is full. value=%d",
                                                                g_PgmName, g_Pid, g_CurrCHPos);
                                                g_Running = FALSE;
                                        }
                                        close(newfd);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    g_Log.Write("[%s:%d][E] accept error. errno = [%d]",
                                                                g_PgmName, g_Pid, errno);
                                        switch(errno)
                                        {
                                        case EMFILE : break;    /* Too many open files */
                                        case ENOENT :       /* No such file or directory */
                                        case EAGAIN :       /* Try again */
                                        case EINVAL :       /* Invalid argument         */
                                        case ENOMSG : ;     /* No message of desired type       */
                                        default :
                                                ResetSocket();
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        else
                                g_Log.Write("[%s:%d] GetEventSock is NULL", g_PgmName, g_Pid);
                }
                else if (n == 0) {
                        currtime = GetTime();
                        if( currtime == 0  && chktime != currtime)
                        {               // ¸ÅÀÏ ÁöÁ¤ÇÑ ½Ã°£ (24½Ã)
                                g_Log.ReOpen();
                                g_MaxUser = 0;
                                ClearTotalTR();
                        }
                        chktime = currtime;
                }
                if (getppid() <= 1){
                        g_Running = FALSE;
                }
                if(WhatTime()) SendWmBoardInfo();
        }
        g_CAgent.Close();

        return FALSE;
}
```

We call the process as WmCL and the WmCL send data to WmCH for connection.

and I got log using strace command the result same as below.

```
select(19, [16 17 18], NULL, NULL, {1, 0}) = 1 (in [17], left {0, 914250})
accept(17, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(38610), sin_addr=inet_addr("114.122.207.70")}, [16]) = 20
sendmsg(9, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{" ", 1}], msg_controllen=24, {cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, {20}}, msg_flags=MSG_OOB|MSG_DONTROUTE|MSG_CTRUNC|0x10}, 0) = 1
close(20)                               = 0
getppid()                               = 17099
select(19, [16 17 18], NULL, NULL, {1, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=344, ...}) = 0
getppid()                               = 17099
select(19, [16 17 18], NULL, NULL, {1, 0}) = 0 (Timeout)
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=344, ...}) = 0
getppid()                               = 17099
select(19, [16 17 18], NULL, NULL, {1, 0}) = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=18976, si_status=0, si_utime=1173, si_stime=797} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 18976
close(7)                                = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=344, ...}) = 0
sendto(19, "m20192.168.103.22 1028360WmCL   "..., 161, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8499), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.201.17")}, 16) = 161
write(5, "[10:28:36-000002][WmCL:17236][E]"..., 63) = 63
socketpair(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0, [7, 20]) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f287d4219f0) = 23210
close(20)                               = 0
```

as following the log, 'select' result is '?' but I don't know why the result is '?'....

Can you advise to me to fix this problem?

Comment: Post errors as text please, not an image.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Sorry my mistake.